# If $x$, $y$, and $z$ are any three positive numbers whose sum is a fixed number $s$, show that $xyz\leq(s/3)^3$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

The question specifies to solve this problem by maximizing $f(x,y)=xy(s-x-y)$ on an appropriate set. I admittedly do not have much of an attempt to post here. My initial thought was to try LaGrange multipliers, but I don't see how that would relate to the choice of "an appropriate set". Any advice on how to approach this is much appreciated.

*Note:* This is independent study material, not coursework.

Comment: Do you know about the Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Comment: This is nothing more or less than the Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean inequality.

Comment: Hmm, on second thought this question tells you to *specifically* prove it by using calculus to maximize it.  But read up on AG-GM.  You should have inspiration.  The "appropriate so is $x, y$ positive.

Comment: @fleablood I was not aware of the AM-GM inequality, but that certainly does help. And the answer posted below would be decent...but you're right, the question asks for maximization. It's already given that $x,y,x$ are positive, so I'm not sure what the appropriate set should be.

Comment: The set where $x,y > 0$ *IS* the appropriate set.  Or $x,y\in \mathbb R^+$.

Comment: D'oh.  I mean the appropriate set is $0 <x,y < s$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if $f(x,y)=xy(s-x-y)$

Then if we solve for $\frac{f(x,y)}{dx}= 0$ and $\frac {f(x,y)}{dy} = 0$ we get

$\frac{f(x,y)}{dx} = y(s - x-y) -xy = 0$ so $ys - y^2 = 2xy$.  The occurs if $y=0$ or if $s-y = 2x$

$\frac{f(x,y)}{dy} = x(s-x-y) - xy = 0$ so $sx-x^2 = 2xy$.  This occurs if $x=0$ or $s- x = 2y$.

As $x,y > 0$ then we have an extreme (a maximum) when $s = 2x -y = 2y-x$ or $x = y = \frac 13 s$.

So $xy(s-x-y) \le (\frac s3)^3$.

Comment: "less than" in your final inequality.

Answer (score 1):

$$xyz~\leq~\left(\frac{s}{3}\right)^3$$

where $s=x+y+z$ the you can derivate

$$\begin{align}xyz~
 &\leq~\left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right)^3\\ \sqrt[3]{xyz}&\leq~\frac{x+y+z}{3}\end{align}$$

where in the last line the L.H.S. is the geometric mean and the R.H.S. is the arithmetic mean and so this inequality is the AM-GM inqueality and you are done.